# SQL Server Configuration Manager , Cannot connect to WMI provider

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-config-manager

I have an virtual "Windows Server 2008" on WMVare . Mssql Server 2012 is installed on it . Sql Server Configuration Manager could be open until some works. 
After I increase amount of RAM(5 GB to 8 GB) and count of core(1 to 2), then this errors give to
[image: Sql Server Configuration Manager When Open]

I have searched for solution, I have found an command to fix it lik

```
mofcomp sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof
```

But. When I run this command on cmd , gives error. I cannot complete work , Like:

[image: Error on cmd]

Comment: Access denied is pretty self explanatory. Are you running this as an Admin account?

Comment: I have an administrator right